# jQuery addClass hidden-xs with transition

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with id "m" and I want to toggle its visibility but only for bootstrap xs, for other sizes I want it visible at all times.

After much fiddling I'm adding and removing the hidden-xs class from the div when clicking another div with id "mf", this works but I can't find anyway to make a transition to make it look smoother. I've tried adding webkit and moz transitions, I've tried fadeIn and fadeOut but nothing gives a transition, heres my code, any suggestions?

```
$('#mf').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   if ($('#m').hasClass('hidden-xs')){
   $('#m').removeClass('hidden-xs');
   }else{
   $('#m').addClass('hidden-xs');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery also had a [method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) `.toggleClass()` that will add the class if the element doesn't already have it and will remove it if the element does have it.  You can try using that maybe it will help.  It would also save you a  few lines, your function could just be

```
$('#mf').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#m').toggleClass('hidden-xs');
});
```

EDIT: UPDATE: CSS transitions will not work with `hidden-xs` as the css it adds is `display: none` and `display` is not animatable, you will have to write a media query with your own class and use `opacity` or `visibility` to hide the element.

Something like this for your CSS:

```
#m {
       -o-transition: 1s ease;
       -ms-transition: 1s ease;
       -moz-transition: 1s ease;
       -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
       transition: 1s ease;
   }
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .custom-hidden-xs {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

and this for your js:

```
$('#mf').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#m').toggleClass('custom-hidden-xs');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well but I still can't get any kind of transition working with it?

Comment: Are you using trying to use CSS to do the transition or js?

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, see if that works for you